# Mac + Mono + VB + LINQ = Not Compiling

Tags: vb.net, macos, linq, mono

Environment: Mac Book Pro / OS X version 10.9.5.
Mono version 3.8.0.
Compiler: VB.NET (vbnc) version 0.0.0.5943.
No IDE. I'm trying to compile an application from the command line.
I'm getting an error and it seems the compiler is not accepting a LINQ expression.
The error message says something like "Expecting End", because my expression is inside a loop. The offending line is like this:

`Dim query = From x In y`

Where y is an array. I tried explicitly referencing System.Core.dll, System.Xml.Linq.dll and using -optioninfer+ flag, but it did not solve the issue.
It seems the compiler is not getting any extended method at all. It does not even recognize the extended method Count for arrays.

Can someone, please, point me to the right direction?
By the way, I cannot install an IDE, I should use the command line compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mono project page for Visual Basic](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/) says that it aims for compatibility with VB 8. Since Linq was introduced in version 9, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the linked page mentions Mono 1.2.3. The one I'm using is 3.8.0. Maybe LINQ is already supported? I do saw there is a System.Xml.Linq.dll file there.

Comment: @user1577561 The library exists (same library that c# uses), but the compiler has no support for it. See https://github.com/mono/mono-basic/blob/master/vbnc/vbnc/source/Enums/Enums.vb for the list of all keywords in the source of the compiler. It doesn't include any of the LINQ keywords.

Comment: As the author of vbnc, this is the correct answer, only VB8 is implemented.